# how to solve Property does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers' error typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hey sorry for the bad english i hope you guys understand what i mean.i have this code below but i get error

problem:

1.for **this.width** and **this.height** Property does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'.
also i get error for

2.**e.target.src**  Property 'src' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
please do tell me in detail what need to change or add because i am really new to typescript

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";

import ImageModal from "../Cropper/imageModal";


const ImageInput = ({
  name,
  onChange,
  showPreview,
  imageData,
  defaultPic,
}:
{name:any,
  onChange:any,
  showPreview:any,
  imageData:any,
  defaultPic:any,}) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null);

  const onChangeHandler = (file:any) => {
    onChange({
      [name]: {
        data: file[0],
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file[0]),
      },
    });
  };

  const handleFile = e => {
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = e.target.files;
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(file[0]);
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.onload = function () {
        setWidth(this.width);
        setHeight(this.height);

      };
  
      const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
      if (file[0].size > maxAllowedSize) {
        console.log("max image size");
      } else {
          setImage(file[0]);
          setModalIsOpen(true);
      }
      e.target.value = null;
    }
  };
  let inputElement:any;

  return (
    <>
      <ImageModal
        modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
        closeModal={() => {
          setModalIsOpen(prevState => !prevState);
        }}
        image={image}
        onCropImage={(croppedImg:any) => onChangeHandler([croppedImg])}
        ratio={height / width <= 0.5 ? true : false}
      />
      {showPreview && (
        <div>

            <img
              key={imageData}
              src={imageData ? imageData : defaultPic}
              className={imageData ? "company-logo" : "default-company-logo"}
              alt="img"
              onError={e => (e.target.src = defaultPic)}
            />
          
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={"upload-image"} onClick={() => inputElement.click()}>
        Upload </div>
      <input
        ref={input => (inputElement = input)}
        accept="image/*"
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange={handleFile}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageInput;
```

Comment: for the second problem I think changing `e.target.src` to `e.currentTarget.src` will work

Answer (score 1):

Now I have made some changes to your original code and I think this should work properly.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";

import ImageModal from "../Cropper/imageModal";

const ImageInput = ({
  name,
  onChange,
  showPreview,
  imageData,
  defaultPic,
}: {
  name: any;
  onChange: any;
  showPreview: any;
  imageData: any;
  defaultPic: any;
}) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState<number | null>(null); 
  const [width, setWidth] = useState<number | null>(null); 

  const onChangeHandler = (file: File) => {
    onChange({
      [name]: {
        data: file,
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      },
    });
  };

  const handleFile = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = e.target.files[0]; // Access the first file
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.onload = function () {
        setWidth(this.width);
        setHeight(this.height);
      };

      const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
      if (file.size > maxAllowedSize) {
        console.log("max image size");
      } else {
        setImage(file);
        setModalIsOpen(true);
      }
      e.target.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ImageModal
        modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
        closeModal={() => {
          setModalIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
        }}
        image={image}
        onCropImage={(croppedImg: File) => onChangeHandler(croppedImg)}
        ratio={height && width ? height / width <= 0.5 : false}
      />
      {showPreview && (
        <div>
          <img
            key={imageData}
            src={imageData ? URL.createObjectURL(imageData) : defaultPic}
            className={imageData ? "company-logo" : "default-company-logo"}
            alt="img"
            onError={(e) => (e.target as HTMLImageElement).src = defaultPic}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={"upload-image"} onClick={() => inputElement.click()}>
        Upload
      </div>
      <input
        ref={(input) => (inputElement = input as HTMLInputElement)}
        accept="image/*"
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange={handleFile}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageInput;
```

Comment: i try to change as you suggest but its still error ,i put my full code above please could you tell me how to solve the error?

Comment: I have updated the code above, try it and it gives error pls let me know'

Comment: still the same it still give GlobalEventHandlers error

Comment: Check if there are any other parts of your code that might be causing the issue. The error message might be related to a different part of your codebase.

Verify that you are not using any conflicting or outdated TypeScript definitions

Comment: Try the updated code

Comment: still the same,i try code from here https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Byurrer/react-load-image-crop/tree/main/?file=/src/ImageLoader.jsx